# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate presenting doesn't work (though dismissing does)

Tags: animation, uikit

I am trying to implement a custom appearing/disappearing animation for a modal `UIViewController` in my app.

I have published [the code showing this error here](https://github.com/JohnRoxMySox23/ModalAppearanceIssue).

Here is the content related:

```
/// The view controller from which I'm trying to display the modal
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func tapped() {
        /// The modal showing
        ModalTestViewController.show()
    }

    //...
}

/// The displayed modal 
open class ModalTestViewController: TransitioningModalViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: "ModalTestViewController", bundle: .main)
        transitioningDelegate = self
        // 1. when I put transitioningDelegate here, case 1
    }
    
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 2. if I put transitioningDelegate here, case 2
    }

    @IBAction func tapped() {
        // a tap on the overlayView of my modal
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    static func show() {
        let modal = ModalTestViewController()
        modal.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.present(modal, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

/// The default modal view controller, which all modals in my app should inherit
open class TransitioningModalViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: View Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var overlayView: UIView!
}

extension TransitioningModalViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    public func animationController(
        forPresented presented: UIViewController,
        presenting: UIViewController,
        source: UIViewController
    ) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return TransitioningModalViewControllerPresenter()
    }
    
    public func animationController(
        forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController
    ) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return TransitioningModalViewControllerDismisser()
    }
}

private final class TransitioningModalViewControllerPresenter: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(
        using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?
    ) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }
    
    func animateTransition(
        using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning
    ) {
        let toViewController: TransitioningModalViewController = transitionContext.viewController(
            forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to
        ) as! TransitioningModalViewController
        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        toViewController.overlayView.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration
        ) {
            toViewController.overlayView.alpha = 0.65
        } completion: { result in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(result)
        }
    }
}

private final class TransitioningModalViewControllerDismisser: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(
        using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?
    ) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }
    
    func animateTransition(
        using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning
    ) {
        let fromViewController: TransitioningModalViewController = transitionContext.viewController(
            forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from
        ) as! TransitioningModalViewController
        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration
        ) {
            fromViewController.overlayView.alpha = 0.0
        } completion: { result in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(result)
        }
    }
}
```

The idea behind this is that the modal appearance should not be the usual bottom-to-top animation, but instead the overlay view should go from hidden to an alpha of 0,65.

- Case 1: when I put `transitioningDelegate = self` in `init()`, the animation is killed and nothing happens.
- Case 2: when I put it into the `viewDidLoad()`, the appearing animation is the default bottom-to-top one, but the disappearing one is the expecting one (with the overlay view vanishing).

It looks like something is wrong with the initial `transitioningDelegate` setting but I can't find what.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: To clarify... you want the presented controller to "fade-in / fade-out"? And, you want the presented controller's **background** to have an alpha of 65% -- but that controller's **UI elements** to have 100% alpha?

Comment: To clarify, my modal view controller (`TransitioningModalViewController`) contains an overlayView whose alpha is supposed to go from 0 to 0.65 during the view presenting, and from 0.65 to 0 during its disappearance. But this process only works for the disappearing animation, not the appearing one, like if the `transitioningDelegate` wasn't set correctly or something was wrong in the `UIView.animate()` call in `TransitioningModalViewControllerPresenter`.

Comment: @DonMag I have added a link to a repo where I have pushed the related code to show more precisely what's happening. If you run the app, you'll see the appearing transition not doing anything special, but the disappearing one with the expected fade-out effect.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think that approach is going to work. At least, not in the current implementation attempt. In your `ModalTestViewController`, you are setting the `transitioningDelegate` inside `viewDidAppear()`. But, that is not called until ***after*** the controller has been presented. If you assign it ***before*** calling `present`, it never shows up because you have overridden the default presentation code.

Comment: @DonMag what surprises me is that I always used this way and never got any issue with it until yesterday. Also, I absolutely understand the `viewDidAppear()` case, but I'm not sure to understand the second case. Thank you for your answers anyway.

Comment: It's a little tough to see your ultimate goal... Do you want the "white bottom panel" to slide-up, and then the `overlayView` to fade-in? Or the `overlayView` to fade-in, and **then** the while panel slides-up?

Comment: After a little experimentation and comparing your approach to other examples, I'm surprised it *ever* worked. See my answer for details and a "fix."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, you are setting the delegate here:

```
open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    transitioningDelegate = self
}
```

However, `.present(...)` is called **before** `viewDidAppear(...)`, so the controller is presented with default slide-up animation.

Setting the delegate in `init()` doesn't work, because we have override the default presentation process... and the presented controller's `view` is never added to the view hierarchy.

This "quick fix" should do the job...

First, in `ModalTestViewController`, move setting the delegate to `init()`:

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: "ModalTestViewController", bundle: .main)
    transitioningDelegate = self
}
```

then, in `TransitioningModalViewControllerPresenter`, add these lines before the animation:

```
func animateTransition(
    using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning
) {
    let toViewController: TransitioningModalViewController = transitionContext.viewController(
        forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to
    ) as! TransitioningModalViewController
    
    // add these lines  \/
    // get the "from" view controller
    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!
    // get the "to" view controller's view
    let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!
    // set the frame of the "to" view to the initialFrame (the current frame) of the "from" VC
    toView.frame = transitionContext.initialFrame(for: fromVC)
    // get the transition container view
    let container = transitionContext.containerView
    // add the "to" view to the view hierarchy
    container.addSubview(toView)
    // add these lines  /\
    
    let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
    toViewController.overlayView.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: duration
    ) {
        toViewController.overlayView.alpha = 0.65
    } completion: { result in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(result)
    }
}
```

Personally, to make this more flexible, I would get rid of your `overlayView` and set the alpha on the controller's `view` itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! From your code it looks like I was missing the `container.addSubview(view)` part in the transition animator.